# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{2}$ over $x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Limit Question:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{2}}{x}$$

After changing the rational expression to an equivalent expression that has the lcd in the numerator, simplifying, and then cancelling out $x$ I got

$$\frac{-x}{2x(x+2)}$$

I substituted $0$ into $x$ and got $0$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "all over x"?

Comment: I mean divided by x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, but be careful about the $x$s both in the denominator and in the numerator.
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}=\frac{2-(x+2)}{2(x+2)x}=\frac{-\color{red}{x}}{2(x+2)\color{red}{x}}=\frac{-1}{2(x+2)}\rightarrow -\frac 14\ (x\rightarrow 0).$$

Comment: What happen to the x in the denominator after one multiplies by the reciprocal?

Comment: I got it they cancel out. Thanks.

Comment: @user137452: You are welcome. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify then pass to the limit

$$\frac{\frac1{x+2}-\frac12}x=\frac{\frac{-x}{2(x+2)}}{x}=-\frac{1}{2(x+2)}\xrightarrow{x\to0}-\frac14$$

Comment: what happen to the x in the denominator?

Comment: Simplified with $x$ in the numerator.